# Why does git diff include already merged commits?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a git repo in Azure DevOps. The repo has a develop branch and a master branch. Our engineers perform PR's from their topic branches to the develop branch, and then we periodically submit a PR to move code from develop to master.

However, we're noticing an odd behavior when creating PRs from develop to master. Specifically, the diff includes past commits (that were already merged) between develop and master, and we're not sure why. This may be exacerbated by merging from develop to master, and then reverting a merged change in develop.

Is there a way to fix these branches so the diffs are what we'd expect (as in, just the delta in code)?

Comment: Did you ever force push? What kind of merge strategy do you use?

Comment: Hi @Craig, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is like the key problem: `This may be exacerbated by merging from develop to master, and then reverting a merged change in develop.`. The other thing is if you are not *really* merging but **squashing** (or rebasing) the changes while keeping dev as it is. Then the last common ancestor doesn't move and then when you see what changes are introduced by dev on a PR into master, you would still see those changes that have been already merged. Might want to take a look at how diff works with you use 3 points instead of 2 (like `master...dev` instead of `master..dev`)